# Mumford-Oda - Algebraic Geometry II . There will be a complete book?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Online there is the draft of a book written  by Mumford and Oda that should be the continuation of "Algebraix Geometry I complex projetive varieties" (Mumford,1976). Do you know if and when this book will be publicated?  This is merely a personal curiosity because I like Mumford's writing style.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That book already exists (in a sense...)!  It is [The Geometry of Schemes](http://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Geometry_of_Schemes.html?id=BpphspzsasEC&redir_esc=y) .
It was originally supposed to be written by Mumford, Eisenbud and Harris, based partially on Mumford's manuscripts.
Mumford retired from the project, since his scientific interest is no longer in algebraic geometry but in computer vision. 
The published book was then written by Eisenbud and Harris alone .
It seems that Mumford's manuscripts (and his Red Book) also are partially at the base of Mumford and Oda's online book and I would guess that publication now depends on Oda alone.
 I'm not very optimistic since these notes have been floating unmodified online for quite some time (this is *really* conjectural: I have never met nor corresponded with Oda).
But who knows...

**Update (November 22, 2015)**
Well now we know: I am happy to announce that  the book has just been published by [Hindustan Book Agency](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=hinseries&ikey=HIN-70)  under the title *Algebraic Geometry II*.
It is described as being a sequel to Mumford's [*Algebraic Geometry I*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540586571), first published by Springer in 1976 (39 years ago!) , but my guess is that this claim and the title of the book are closer to commercial hype "suggested" to the authors than to an honest description of the contents.